# Javascript sample program not working

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to run a sample javascript code from the link:   [Link](http://reazulk.wordpress.com/2008/06/19/barcode-reader-and-javascript/)

Nothing happens on FF and on IE, after scanning, it just clears out the text field.  What is the issue here?

Code:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>

<script type="javascript">
    function ini()
    {

    // Retrieve the code
    var code =document.getElementById ('code_read_box').value;

    alert(code);

    // Return false to prevent the form to submit
    return false;

    }

</script>

</head>


<body>

    <form onsubmit = "return ini()">

    <input type="text" id="code_read_box" value="" />

    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: We have no way of telling what errors you made when trying to write a script based on a couple of snippets of code when you give us the document but not what you've actually produced.

Comment: Hi David, I added the code. Sorry I am not able to format it correctly on this page.

Comment: 4 spaces before a line formats as code. To do this for a block, select it and press `ctr-k`

Comment: @t3ch, just a minor typo in the site you link to (I'm assuming it's your site, obviously): "Experince" is spelled "Experience" unless it's deliberately misspelled.

Comment: @ David, lol.. Its not my site :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```html
<script type="text/javascript">
```

instead of

```
<script type="javascript">
```

Answer (score 0):

"The Issue" can be any one of a multitude of things.  Are you sure the JS code is being loaded?  Is there an error in the JS console?  Have you tried to use something like [firebug](http://getfirebug.com/) to see what's actually happening?

Without more information, there's no way we can guess what's actually going on.

Answer (score 0):

This works:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Untitled Document</title>
</head>
<body>

    <form onsubmit="return ini()">
        <input type="text" id="code_read_box">
    </form>

    <script>
        function ini() {
            var code = document.getElementById('code_read_box').value;
            alert(code);
            return false;
        }
    </script>

</body>
</html>
```

The same thing but with use of jQuery:
(this will make it work in IE)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Untitled Document</title>
</head>
<body>

    <form id="foo">
        <input type="text" id="code_read_box">
    </form>

    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $("#foo").submit(function() {
                alert( $("#code_read_box").val() );
                return false;
            });
        });
    </script>

    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Hi Sime Vidas, What was wrong with the posted code? I see you removed value from the input tag.

Comment: The type="javascript" attribute of the SCRIPT element. Just use type="text/javascript" or do not set the type attribute altogether (I don't)

Comment: My code works in FF, Safari, Chrome and Opera. I only have IE9 beta here and it works in that browser only after the 3rd submit. In what browsers doesn't it work for you?